# SQLCMD Restore is not restoring all sprocs

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using the following command in order to restore a database as a part of an installation of a program.

```
SqlCmd -S .\<SqlInstance> -h -1 -U <username> -P <password> -Q "RESTORE DATABASE <Database> FROM DISK=<FilePath>"
```

When I run this command, the database restores successfully, but there is a single sproc that does not exist. However, when I take the same file and restore the database through SSMS, that sproc does exist and the database restores correctly. This is the only difference between the two methods of restoring the database and I cannot manage every install manually, as this will be installed to over 300 machines.

If there is any other information I can give in order for clarification I am happy to provide it.

EDIT:

AS per the comments I found the T-SQL command being executed

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [ErplyAnalysis] FROM  DISK = N'<FilePath>' WITH  FILE = 2,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

Comment: If the databases differ then what you're doing isn't the same. Perhaps you have multiple backup sets in the backup and your restoring different ones?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check if that is the case?

Comment: What is the T-SQL you're running when you restore in SSMS?

Comment: I'm not running a T-SQL command when I restore, I am just right clicking on the database folder in the Explorer Window and clicking "Restore Database"

Comment: *"I'm not running a T-SQL command when I restore"*  Yes you are. That's *how* you restore. Just because you're using a GUI doesn't change the fact that all it does is run a T-SQL statement after you click a few buttons. What is that T-SQL statement?

Comment: SSMS does not have a special magic hotline to SQL Server -- it will issue a `RESTORE DATABASE` command in the background (along with some other commands to determine the metadata). To distinguish the cases, you can click the "Script" button to script it separately, or use SQL Server Profiler (Tools -> Profiler) to trace the SQL SSMS executes for restore. As there "shouldn't be any difference", this is a curious case indeed -- the only thing I can think of (aside from user error) is a server trigger that creates the sproc on demand, which for some reason behaves differently.

Comment: I've edited the post with the T-SQL command

Comment: *"`WITH  FILE = 2,`"* BOOM. Called it in my first comment ;) You're restoring different backup sets. The second in SSMS and the first in `sqlcmd`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. If it works could you please add your comment as an answer and if it works as expected I will accept that as the answer. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: That did indeed work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're restoring different backup sets in the different commands. If we solely look at the 2 statements you have:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE <Database> FROM DISK=<FilePath>
```

And then in SSMS:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [ErplyAnalysis] FROM  DISK = N'<FilePath>' WITH  FILE = 2,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS =
```

Notice in SSMS you have `FILE = 2`.

By default, if `FILE` is omitted then it will use its default value of `1` (see [RESTORE Arguments (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). As a result, in `sqlcmd` you are restoring an older version of your database.

You have 2 sets as you didn't reinitialise the backup when you made it. That isn't a problem, but it means you need to ensure you check which value you need to pass for `FILE` is you are using backup sets.